# Spring Boot: Testing ResponseEntity Containing Java Time

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking

I need to test a Rest API response body that holds a `java.time.Instant` field. Unfortunately, the test cannot be passed because of milliseconds difference between actual and expected timestamps. I'm just wondering how I can mock the system clock or somehow configure the test context to make the test pass:

*Response body class:*

```
public class ApiError {
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private Instant timestamp;
    private List<ErrorDetail> errorDetails;

    public ApiError(HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
        this.timestamp = Instant.now();
    }

// the rest of class is omitted for brevity
}
```

*The test class:*

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;
    ApiError apiError;

    @Test
    public void givenBlankField_WhenRequestIsReceived_ThenApiErrorGenerated() throws Exception {
        SignUpRequest request = new SignUpRequest()
                .setFirstName(" ")  //validation error occurs
                .setLastName("Doe")
                .setPassword("123")
                .setConfirmPassword("123")
                .setEmail("john.doe@something.com")
                .setConfirmEmail("john.doe@something.com");

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/users/signup")
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest()).andReturn();

        String actualResponseBody = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        // Excpected response body:
        apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        FieldValidationErrorDetail errorDetail = new FieldValidationErrorDetail.Detail()
                .field("firstName").message("{NotBlank.firstName}").rejectedValue(" ").build();
        apiError.setErrorDetails(List.of(errorDetail));
        String expectedResponseBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(apiError);

        assertEquals(expectedResponseBody, actualResponseBody); //fails due to milliseconds difference between actual timestamp and expected timestamp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

Here you are instantiating the `timestamp` field at two different times and comparing them.  They will always fail to match.

**Solution**

I would recommend avoiding the instantiation of `new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)` in your test and simply verifying each field individually.  For the `timestamp` field, just verify that it is set to a non-null value or if you want to get pedantic, verify that it has a value within the last X number of seconds instead of the precise millisecond validation that you are currently checking.

**Alternative Solution (Hacky Workaround)**

If you want to continue validation a JSON string against a JSON string, simply convert the response body into an object and steal it's timestamp into your comparison object.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm actually looking for a way to mock the system clock. I found some techniques on the internet to override the clock but couldn't apply them to my test case successfully. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You may go to way more trouble than it is worth to mock the system clock.  I don't see any added value to doing so.  You can always just set the field of your new ApiError() to the same values as the received one if you wish to set the field to the same value but again, I'm not sure what this accomplishes.